# HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"

Tags: html, vb.net, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I've got a legacy app just starting to misbehave, for whatever reason I'm not sure.  It generates a bunch of HTML that gets turned into PDF reports by ActivePDF.

The process works like this:

1. Pull an HTML template from a DB with tokens in it to be replaced (e.g. "~CompanyName~", "~CustomerName~", etc.)
2. Replace the tokens with real data
3. Tidy the HTML with a simple regex function that property formats HTML tag attribute values (ensures quotation marks, etc, since ActivePDF's rendering engine hates anything but single quotes around attribute values)
4. Send off the HTML to a web service that creates the PDF.

Somewhere in that mess, the non-breaking spaces from the HTML template (the `&nbsp;`s) are encoding as ISO-8859-1 so that they show up incorrectly as an "Â" character when viewing the document in a browser (FireFox).  ActivePDF pukes on these non-UTF8 characters.

My question: since I don't know where the problem stems from and don't have time to investigate it, is there an easy way to re-encode or find-and-replace the bad characters?  I've tried sending it through this little function I threw together, but it <strike>turns it all into gobbledegook</strike> doesn't change anything.

```
Private Shared Function ConvertToUTF8(ByVal html As String) As String
    Dim isoEncoding As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
    Dim source As Byte() = isoEncoding.GetBytes(html)
    Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(isoEncoding, Encoding.UTF8, source))
End Function
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I'm getting by with this for now, though it hardly seems like a good solution:

```
Private Shared Function ReplaceNonASCIIChars(ByVal html As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(html, "[^\u0000-\u007F]", "&nbsp;")
End Function
```

Comment: Does the HTML contain any meta informaiton to describe its character set?

Comment: [Previous commented deleted] Short answer: no.

Comment: For me worked: utf8_decode()

Answer (score 393, accepted):

> Somewhere in that mess, the non-breaking spaces from the HTML template (the  s) are encoding as ISO-8859-1 so that they show up incorrectly as an "Â" character

That'd be encoding to UTF-8 then, not ISO-8859-1. The non-breaking space character is byte 0xA0 in ISO-8859-1; when encoded to UTF-8 it'd be 0xC2,0xA0, which, if you (incorrectly) view it as ISO-8859-1 comes out as `"Â "`. That includes a trailing nbsp which you might not be noticing; if that byte isn't there, then something else has mauled your document and we need to see further up to find out what.

What's the regexp, how does the templating work? There would seem to be a proper HTML parser involved somewhere if your `&nbsp;` strings are (correctly) being turned into U+00A0 NON-BREAKING SPACE characters. If so, you could just process your template natively in the DOM, and ask it to serialise using the ASCII encoding to keep non-ASCII characters as character references. That would also stop you having to do regex post-processing on the HTML itself, which is always a highly dodgy business.

Well anyway, for now you can add one of the following to your document's `<head>` and see if that makes it look right in the browser:

- for HTML4: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`
- for HTML5: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

If you've done that, then any remaining problem is ActivePDF's fault.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `<meta charset="utf-8">` yet. The `http-equiv` version is still valid in HTML5 and is better-supported.

Comment: Answers from [Which one to Use: <meta charset='utf-8'> vs <meta http-equiv='Content-Type'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/which-one-to-use-meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type) state that the short version is well supported.

Comment: Found another source [This works in all browsers](http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html#encoding)

Comment: It works in all *modern* browsers. It certainly doesn't work in all legacy and niche (eg mobile) browsers, or on all spiders.

Comment: "Somewhere in that mess"... LOL! Nice open! Good answer! +1

Comment: Nice one, had the same issue with asp.net and AspPDF PDF generator. Placed it in the head of the page and it's all fine now.

Comment: Works on TuesPechkin HTML/PDF generator in .NET too. Great fix!

Comment: https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_HTML_Entity()Encode_text('ISO-8859-1%20Latin%201%20Western%20European%20(28591)')Encode_text('UTF-8%20(65001)')&input=Jm5ic3A7

Answer (score 25):

If any one had the same problem as me and the charset was already correct, simply do this:

1. Copy all the code inside the .html file.
2. Open notepad (or any basic text editor) and paste the code.
3. Go "File -> Save As"
4. Enter you file name "example.html" (Select "Save as type: All Files (*.*)")
5. Select Encoding as UTF-8
6. Hit Save and you can now delete your old .html file and the encoding should be fixed

Comment: This did it for me. Now in sublime it says `UTF-8 with BOM` instead of `UTF-8`. To see this in sublime text, you need `show_encoding` set to `true` in Settings - User.

Comment: I had the problem that showing Â instead of » , amd When Using this solution the problem solved but there is a php warning:  `Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at D:\Program Files\wamp\wamp\www\projects\kerala\kerala_public_html\edit\business_details.php:1) in D:\Program Files\wamp\wamp\www\projects\kerala\kerala_public_html\user\include\fg_membersite.php on line 152`

Comment: This solution worked for me. I was working in notepad++, and when I saved it in basic ms notepad as UTF-8, after opening the new file in notepad++, the encoding was set to UTF-8-BOM (which I am not sure what means). Anyway, that seems to have been the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. I see in the request/response the file (in my case, ASPX) was encoded as UTF-8. Notepad++ had it encoded to UTF-8, also. What the heck, right? But you're solution did the trick. For me, it was a Spanish phrase that wasn't encoding properly on the page. I've read elsewhere not to use UTF-8 BOM for Spanish but it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 16):

**Problem:**
Even I was facing the problem where we were sending **'£'** with some string in POST request to CRM System, but when we were doing the GET call from CRM , it was returning **'Â£'** with some string content. So what we have analysed is that **'£'** was getting converted to **'Â£'**.

**Analysis:**
The glitch which we have found after doing research is that in POST call we have set HttpWebRequest **ContentType as "text/xml"** while in GET Call it was **"text/xml; charset:utf-8"**.

**Solution:**
So as the part of solution we have included the **charset:utf-8** in POST request and it works.

Answer (score 3):

In my case this (a with caret) occurred in code I generated from visual studio using my own tool for generating code. It was easy to solve:

Select single spaces ( ) in the document. You should be able to see lots of single spaces that are looking different from the other single spaces, they are not selected. Select these other single spaces - they are the ones responsible for the unwanted characters in the browser. Go to Find and Replace with single space ( ). Done.

PS: It's easier to see all similar characters when you place the cursor on one or if you select it in VS2017+; I hope other IDEs may have similar features

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was getting latin cross sign instead of nbsp, even that a page was correctly encoded into the UTF-8. Nothing of above helped in resolving the issue and I tried all.

In the end changing font for IE (with browser specific css) helped, I was using Helvetica-Nue as  a body font changing to the Arial resolved the issue .

Comment: The reason why switching the font may have helped may be because one of the fonts didn't contain the character in question, so what you saw was an empty character, instead. But this didn't solve the problem, it only covered it up.

Answer (score -3):

The reason for this is PHP doesn't recognise utf-8.

Here you can check it for all Special Characters in HTML

http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Comment: This was not a question about PHP, it's VB.NET.

Comment: i no, but you can use these characters to solve the problem . this fixed my solution.

Comment: This was actually the most helpful answer for me. The mention of PHP is what has put others off I assume, but the priciple is universal. So rather than faffing with context type or encoding configurations, in my case I just had to replace the £ character with &pound;

Answer (score -3):

Well I got this Issue too in my few websites and all i need to do is customize the content fetler for HTML entites. before that more i delete them more i got, so just change you html fiter or parsing function for the page and it worked. Its mainly due to HTML editors in most of CMSs. the way they store parse the data caused this issue (In My case). May this would Help in your case too

Answer (score -4):

I was having the same sort of problem.  Apparently it's simply because PHP doesn't recognise utf-8.

I was tearing my hair out at first when a '£' sign kept showing up as 'Â£', despite it appearing ok in DreamWeaver.  Eventually I remembered I had been having problems with links relative to the index file, when the pages, if viewed directly would work with slideshows, but not when used with an include (but that's beside the point.  Anyway I wondered if this might be a similar problem, so instead of putting  into the page that I was having problems with, I simply put it into the index.php file - problem fixed throughout.