# Getting an extended-character for any control with an icon in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've dealt with and fixed this problem for this app once before, but I don't recall *exactly* what fixed it. The only thing I remember doing is downloading fresh copies of jQuery, jQuery Mobile, etc; but I've done that again and it hasn't fixed the issue.

[image]

This character, "Â" shows up for every control that would have an icon, like listviews with a ">", and the buttons seen here.

The character is actually being added to the source of the page as jQM is modifying it (see the span contents):

```
<a data-icon="maps" id="maps-button" data-role="button" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/map/" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-a">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Maps</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-maps ui-icon-shadow">Â </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp Maybe add this meta tag as well: <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. You should post it as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Related:

- [HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)

Maybe add this meta tag as well: `<meta charset="utf-8">`