# Adding text into textarea adds extra character. What causes this?

Tags: html, textarea, ascii

Does anyone know why I see this extra character when I put pre-generated data in my textarea?

http://i.imgur.com/k4y1D.png

The character is "Â’"

Comment: It's probably an encoding problem

Comment: This has already been addressed and resolved. (google is a wonderful tool) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can try to open your code in an editor like Notepad++ which used UTF-8 encoding and remove the character. I had this issue and the character didn't show up using Visual Studio 2010 or Sublime.

Comment: Either you put it there, or some software you use puts it there, or your document is somehow messed up (e.g., wrong encoding). You can’t really expect a more accurate answer without showing any code.