# CKEditor adds div and some unawanted characters in my text

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor for a backend in my web app. When I copy and paste text from another place, it adds `<div>Â</div>` at the end of the copy pasted text, This even become worse when I post into a database. It adds a lot of the `Â` and character in unwanted areas. How can I resolve this?I also have jQuery libraries in my web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the page encoding from `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>` to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Paste as Plain Text" button for all pasting. This one: [image: CKEditor Paste as Plain Text]