# what is the code to remove this symbol- Â in html

Tags: html

does any one know why that symbol is there next to the copyright? R&W Brokerage Inc. Â© 2013 does anyone know how to get rid of it this is what i have it saying and then on the web page that little symbol comes up.
R&W Brokerage Inc. © 2013

Answer (score 22):

That happens because the page isn't being displayed in UTF-8 encoding while your HTML source is encoded as such (but probably lacks the byte order mark that indicates UTF-8 encoding). Put either the HTML4 `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` or the HTML5 `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside the `<head>` element.

(The reason I know that specifically is the issue is that I just had the same issue, albeit with a Python script being opened in a text editor that doesn't auto-detect that the encoding is UTF-8 if the BOM or a file encoding directive isn't included.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the © code ?
Can you show us the source of your code ?
Did you try to change the encoding in your browser ? try with firefox to change the encoding, if changing the encoding fixes the displaying of the copyright caracter, that means that you have a encoding problem ..

Comment: <div class="copyright" style="margin-top:738px; color:white; margin-left:-500px; width:300px; position:absolute;">
  <p>R&W Brokerage Inc.© 2013</p>
 </div>

Comment: use `&copy;` instead. Make sure your html file is saved in utf-8, and set your charset page to utf-8 also

Answer (score 0):

You might have an encoding problem. check out [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp) answer that was posted a few months ago..