# Unexpected character in HTML file

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on an assignment that creates a webpage that gets an XML file using AJAX.

I'm using Text Wrangler as a simple text editing application and I'm saving and loading the files onto Cyber Duck as a SFTP.

However, when I click on the HTML file on my desktop to open it in Firefox (as well as in other browsers), where I am expecting an 'onclick' that says "Click me", it says "ClickÂ me" and then nothing happens when I click it.

When I right click to "View page source", I see "Â" randomly dispersed throughout the source file.

What would be causing this to happen?

I've read something as it being interpreted as ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 on Firefox? If this is the problem, how do I fix this?

Comment: can you please add your code, so we can help.

Comment: show your code ???????

Answer (score 0):

To fix to UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1

use explicit via `meta` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

See if that character appears again

Answer (score 0):

This is the   character

Use UTF-8 in your HTML files as per

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

see also [HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)