# "Â " character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp) which describes my issue pretty well and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1462039/817379) answer describes my issue exactly.

> The non-breaking space character is byte 0xA0 is ISO-8859-1; when encoded to UTF-8 it'd be 0xC2,0xA0, which, if you (incorrectly) view it as ISO-8859-1 comes out as `"Â "`. That includes a trailing nbsp...

However, I have managed to track my issue down to a function I use to wrap image tags in divs.

```
function img_format($str)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($str);     // <-- Bonus points for the explaination of the @

    // $tags object
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {

        $div = $doc->createElement('div');
        $div->setAttribute('class','inner-copy');
        $tag->parentNode->insertBefore($div, $tag);
        $div->appendChild($tag);

        $tag->setAttribute('class', 'inner-img');
    }

    $str = $doc->saveHTML();

    return $str;
}
```

Quite simply, how can I fix this issue within this function?

I understand using;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

will fix this issue, but there is obviously something I'm overlooking within the function itself.

I've tried;

```
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
```

To no avail. (I don't quite know what that does anyway)

Comment: I'm just trying to get the bonus point: The `@` suppresses any errors thrown by the expression they've been placed in front of. So in case the method call of `$doc->loadHTML($str);` throws an error, you won't see an error/warning message. You can read more about it in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it!

```
@$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/817379) explains the issue and gives the work around above;

> DOMDocument::loadHTML will treat your string as being in ISO-8859-1 unless you tell it otherwise. This results in UTF-8 strings being interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: Don't forget, you should be able to set your own answer as the accepted one.