# How to remove &nbsp spaces from html content in react native?

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native, webview

In my project I'm loading an html content using `WebView` of react native.But the problem is I'm getting unwanted characters in the result.What I meant is the html contents contain `&nbsp` these are rendered in react native as some unwanted characters along with the text.I've tried `regex` to remove that, but not working.Following is my code please help.

**code**

```
<Content contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1}}>
     {this.state.data.map(item =>
       <View style={{flex:1,padding:10}}>
        <Text style={{textAlign:'center', margin:15,fontSize:20,fontWeight:'bold'}}>{item.data.course.name}</Text>
        <WebView
        source={{ html: item.data.description.replace(/^\s*&nbsp;/m, '') + htmlStyle }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
         />
         </View>
         )}
      </Content>
```

Following is the screenshot

[image]

**json**

```
data:
course: {id: 5506, name: "Balance of Payment Account: Meaning and Significance"}
curriculum: false
description: "<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Guide to the module: </strong></p>↵<p style="text-align: justify;">              This module deals with the balance of payment account concepts from the Indian context. At the later part, a typical balance of payment scenario of India is illustrated by taking 2012-13 financial year as an example.</p>↵<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Balance of payment account</strong></p>↵<p style="text-align: justify;">           Balance of payment systematically shows the whole types of economic engagement between residents of India and the residents of the rest of the world. The transaction details are usually shown for a period (like one year).
```

Comment: can you add a `console.log(item.data.description)`?

Comment: Sorry I'm loading `WebView` I can't console the result.This is the real WebView content  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNRID.png .I'm using this content in my app.So this is how it should come

Comment: try `.replace(/^[\s\xa0]+/g, '')`

Comment: Still getting the same no change :(

Comment: you can console out `this.state.data`

Comment: Yes I've edited my question with json o/p please check.

Comment: try `.replace(/[^\w .,\-()]/g, '')`

Comment: Spaces are removed but `p` tag is there also the apllied styles aro not coming.This is how it will be https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7pEh.png

Comment: maybe `.replace(/>[^\w]+/g, '>')`

Comment: @ic3b3rg this is what I'm getting  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsQKr.png

Comment: with `.replace(/>[^\w]+/g, '>')`?

Comment: @ic3b3rg yes applied styles are not coming also some characters are not replaced

Comment: another stab: `.replace(/>[\xc2 ]+/g, '>')`

Comment: Actually no change same  as the begining.

Comment: This is the issue you're dealing with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502051/%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp - `.replace(/[\xc2\xa0]+/g, '')` *should* work

Comment: if that doesn't work, maybe the `&nbsp;` is actually there in the input - your original regex wouldn't catch them because of the `^` anchor - try `.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '')`

Comment: @ic3b3rg yes it worked for me thank you so much..But still there is small issue with apostrophe.

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: All apostrophe will be rendered like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJIrK.png

Comment: try `decodeURIComponent(escape(item.data.description))`

Comment: Sorry how it will be within `WebView` I've tried this `source={{ html: decodeURIComponent(escape(item.data.description)) + htmlStyle }}` but getting error as URI malformed

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove all `&nbsp;`

```
replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '');
```