# Remove non-standard characters from html PHP

Tags: php

How can i remove only � (using curl To get data)

```
$str = "Check this out <a href=�http://www.somewebsite.com�>Somewebsite</a>, this is a great website
Windows� (XP 32bit/Vista/7/8/8.1)";
```

I just want � to be removed.
I tried

```
$output = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$str);
```

it remove html also ... but i want html

Comment: What are you ask? To solve your problem with the encoding or just to remove the characters that do not belong to the encoding of the string?

Comment: @Leggendario Sorry ... i did not mention before ... i am using curl to get this data....

Comment: You have an **encoding problem** which you need to solve by **handling encodings correctly.** Not by removing "incorrect" characters.

Comment: @deceze i am using UTF-8 ... and try others also nut same result .... which encoding should i use ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%c3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)

Comment: @Harinder if the above duplicate doesn't help - look for one of the **many** other duplicate question terms to search for: html utf8 BOM encoding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a bad work-around like that, you should fix your charset issue instead. Your problem is likely that you don't use the same character-encoding in all levels of your application/scripts. Anything that has or can be set to a specific character-encoding, should be set to the same. The most general ones are below.

- Save the document as UTF-8 (or UTF8 w/o BOM) (If you're using Notepad++, it's Format -> Convert to UFT-8 or UTF8 w/o BOM)
- The header in both PHP and HTML should be set to UTF-8

  - HTML: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`, inside the `<head>`-tag in your document.
  - PHP: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` - PHP headers has to be set BEFORE **any** output is made (no HTML, no whitespace, no echo/print - nothing).

There are other aspects as well that might need to be set to UTF-8, it depends on what kind of PHP functions you are using and so on. But the above is generally a good start.