# Parsing a UTF-8 encoded web page

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

If I recive some data from a website I get the following string:

```
Peter Tester &nbsp; â‚‹ &nbsp;&nbsp;Max Mustermann
```

The meta infos of the homepage shows me that the encoding is UTF-8, I wrote a little function to convert UTF-8 to Base64 (Base64 is the correct charset for default C# projects or?)

```
private String UTF8toBase64(string input)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}
```

But this function returns a string like this:

```
"S3lsZSBFZG11bmQgJm5ic3A7IMOi4oCa4oC5ICZuYnNwOyZuYnNwO0ppcmkgVmVzZWx5"
```

Comment: Base64 is for encoding unrepresentable data, default encoding is Default which is different on each system, it depends on the machine locale.

Comment: If you have a string then it means you already parsed your input stream as UTF-16. Probably original text can't be recovered (if you didn't get any encoding exception...) and you can't recover it. You have to apply _conversion_ on input byte stream. BTW Base64 has nothing to do with UTF8...

Comment: When you receive data from the web site, you're receiving *bytes*. I'd start from there. If those bytes are meant to be UTF-8-encoded text, use `Encoding.UTF8` to decode it. Base64 is unrelated here.

Comment: I recive the web site and "parse" it with the HTMLAgilityPack. After parsing the page I want to filter some values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want:

```
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread with the same problem in VB

[HTML encoding issues - “Â” character showing up instead of “ ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)

The same function in C# works nice, after replacing the "â‚‹" with   Ive got a string I can work with :-)

Thanks for help people

```
Regex.Replace(input, "[^\u0000-\u007F]", "&nbsp;")
```