# javascript encodeURI() output

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI), The 'encodeURI()' function:

> replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character

However, when invoking `encodeURI('\u0082')` (in Chrome) Im getting `%C2%81` as output.

I expected to get `%82` or `%00%82`. What does the `%C2` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '0082' in '\u0082' is the *Unicode* code point, not the UTF-8 bytes representation.
UTF-8 maps `u+0082` code point to two bytes: `C2+81`

[Unicode to UTF-8 mapping table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

Answer (score 0):

Decoding `%C2` at http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php leads to `Â`

When dealing with German texts and ISO 8859-15 / ISO 8859-1 vs. UTF-8 I often ran into the `Ã` character. The characters are quite close to each other. May this also be an encoding problem?

Maybe [HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp) helps.