# Why HTML and CSS doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm learning HTML and CSS on W3Schools and now I've stuck at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) chapter. Beforehand I want to say that I'm learning it at my Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (with Android 5.1.1). I'm using the [AWD - IDE For Web dev](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kidinov.awd&hl=en), [Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander&hl=en), [Samsung Internet Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.sbrowser&hl=en) and [Google Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en).

My problem is, that I don't know why my HTML and CSS doesn't work.

When I'm trying to define the CSS-Styling in a extern file [I get this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpETh.jpg)

So there are two questions I have. **Where does the `ÁÁ` come from and why the HTML-Document is'nt designed as in CSS definded.**

When I'm trying to define the CSS-Styling intern [I get this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yFv2.jpg)

Then the background just changes but the heading and the paragraph doesn't.

The code that I'm used at my phone is a one-to-one copy from the chapter from W3Schools. I've also tried this with other Browsers and editors, but still doesn't work. I've also noticed that when I save the extern css-file in a own folder `css/styles.css` that I get the same result as the css-stylesheet intern.

**But my final question is: What's wrong with that?**

[Here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11582495/SecWebpage.zip.html) is the project folder from this problem.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Android besides you are testing it on an Android phone?

Comment: @I'm doing this on android because its more confortable, I'm learning webdevelopment by the way in the subway ;-)

Comment: Why I'm getting downvoted?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the odd characters are caused by some sort of improper character encoding which could be caused by your IDE.

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Dyf.png) is what I see when I open your styles.css file in the firefox dev tools page inspector. Clear that up and the external sheet should work properly.

You should also declare a `!DOCTYPE` as well as encoding. It helps to ensure that the browser renders the type of html you're expecting. A more thorough explanation can be found [here.](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype)

i.e. `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: The `index.html` file provided in the zip doesn't include a link to the external stylesheet either. (The `<style>` tag also has the same character encoding problem, though)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread - you're probably experiencing the same thing: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp[enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp%5Benter) link description here][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)
tldr: There's a non-printing character that isn't getting encoded as you'd expect and it spits out this odd character. It should disappear if you set your character coding explicitly using .

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between the element declaration and the keys.

Ex.:

```
body{background-color:red;}
h1{color:blue;}
p{color:green;}
```