# DownloadString and then writing to a page issue

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading the content from a page using `DownloadString` from the `WebClient` class and then writing the contents of that to a static HTML file using the `StreamWriter` class.  On the page that I'm reading in, there's an inline javascript method that just sets an anchor element's `OnClick` attribute to set the `window.location = history.go(-1);`  I'm finding when I view the static HTML page, there's an odd looking letter showing up that isn't present on the dynamic web page.

**WebClient & SteamWriter Code**

```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var html = client.DownloadString(url);

            //This constructor prepares a StreamWriter (UTF-8) to write to the specified file or will create it if it doesn't already exist
            using (var stream = new StreamWriter(file, false, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                stream.Write(html);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
```

**The dynamic page's HTML snippet in question**

```
<span>Sorry, but something went wrong on our end. &nbsp;Click <a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = history.go(-1);">here</a> to go back to the previous page.</span>
```

**The static page's HTML snippet**

```
<span>Sorry, but something went wrong on our end. Â&nbsp;Click <a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = history.go(-1);">here</a> to go back to the previous page.</span>
```

I was thinking that adding the `Encoding.UTF8` parameter would solve this issue but it didn't seem to help.  Is there some sort of extra encoding or decoding that I need to do?  Or did I completely miss something else that's needed for this type of operation?

Comment: perhaps this is what you're seeing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the WebClient to encode in UTF8 as it converts the resource into a string, seems to have taken care of the issue.

```
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                var html = client.DownloadString(url);

                //This constructor prepares a StreamWriter (UTF-8) to write to the specified file or will create it if it doesn't already exist
                using (var stream = new StreamWriter(file, false, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    stream.Write(html);
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
```