# Why does the Â character show on my HTML page?

Tags: html, web

I am coding a website that has information about temperature. I put the degrees symbol (the tiny circle) but now when my page loads, I get Â? Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Found the answer. I had copied and pasted the degrees symbol straight into Sublime Text. What I should have done was used &deg; .

Comment: I believe you can post your comment as the answer to help people that stumble upon this. Not everybody reads the comments under the question. They read the answer first.

Comment: @El'Magnifico Thanks, did it.

Comment: You should have a read of [_The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)_](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), it will help you understand things like this. In this case your HTML file was in UTF-8 encoding, but you were viewing it as (probably) ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Here it is.

I had copied and pasted the degrees symbol straight into Sublime Text. What I should have done was used `&deg;` .

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes despite using HTML symbols your browser might render them weird. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp) for a better explanation.

Comment: Please consider explaining what could be happening instead of just posting a link. Links have a habit of breaking or moving.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `&deg;` as it will render as the degrees symbol.

So let's say you want to write 25°C, you can write:

25`&deg;`C