# Python 0xff byte

Tags: python, file, unicode, utf-8, byte

I got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position: 0, invalid start byte
```

I found this solution:

```
>>> b"abcde".decode("utf-8")
```

from here: 
[Convert bytes to a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string)

But how do you use it if a) you don’t know where the 0xff is and/or b) you need to decode a file object? What is the correct syntax / format?

I am parsing through a directory, so I tried going through the files one at a time. (NOTE: This won't work when the project gets larger!!!)

```
>>> i = "b'0xff'"
>>> with open('firstfile') as f:
...     g=f.readlines()
... 
>>> i in g
False
>>> 0xff in g
False
>>> '0xff' in g
False
>>> b'0xff' in g
False

>>> with open('secondfile') as f:
<snip - same process>

>>> with open('thirdfile') as f:
...     g = f.readlines()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

So if this is the right file, and if I can't open it with Python (I put it in sublime text, found nothing) how do I decode, or encode, this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a number of problems:

- `i = "b'0xff'"` Creates a string of 7 bytes, not a single 0xFF byte.  `i = b'\xff'` or `i = bytes([0xff])` is the correct method.
- `open` defaults to decoding files using the encoding returned by `local.getpreferredencoding(False)`.  Open in binary mode to get raw un-decoded bytes: `open('firstfile','rb')`.
- `g=f.readlines()` returns a list of lines.  `i in g` checks for an *exact match* of the content of i to the content of a line in the line list.
- Use meaningful variable names!

Instead:

```
byte = b'\xff'
with open('firstfile','rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
if byte in file_content:
   ...
```

To decode a file, you need to know it's correct encoding and provide it when you open the file:

```
with open('firstfile',encoding='utf8') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
```

If you don't know the encoding, the 3rd party `chardet` module can help you guess.

Comment: I'd give 1+ for chardet. This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp was also very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

```
#how to decode byte 0xff in python
```

As we know this is hexadecimal encoding so , utf-8 , codec and other decoders are not able to decode this byte into string.  Here we will use 'UTF-16'  or 'utf-16' encoding to decode the 0xff byte array into string or ASCII character.

Let me help you understand this:

```
st = "this world is very beautiful"
print(st.encode('utf-16'))
>>>b'\xff\xfet\x00h\x00i\x00s\x00 \x00w\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00 \x00i\x00s\x00 \x00v\x00e\x00r\x00y\x00 \x00b\x00e\x00a\x00u\x00t\x00i\x00f\x00u\x00l\x00'
```

Again we want to convert it into simple ASCII characters.
There are two method by which we can decode a 0xff code to simple string.

```
st = b'\xff\xfet\x00h\x00i\x00s\x00 \x00w\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00 \x00i\x00s\x00 \x00v\x00e\x00r\x00y\x00 \x00b\x00e\x00a\x00u\x00t\x00i\x00f\x00u\x00l\x00'
```

**First is:**

```
print(str(st, "utf-16"))
```

**Second is:**

```
print(st.decode('UTF-16'))
```

We will get the string as output:

```
>>>'this world is very beautiful'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `try/except` to catch the `UnicodeDecodeError`, then you know that's the file where you have the error.

Most likely that file was not encoded in UTF-8.  In this case you might want to read the file in as either binary:

```
with open('thirdfile', 'rb') as f:
    g = f.readlines()
```

How to figure out the file's encoding is a different problem.