# Graphiql app shows extra garbage characters

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, character-encoding, graphql, graphiql

I recently deployed the graphiql web app onto an embedded device that I work with and the page is marked up with extra accented "A" characters.  What could be causing this?

Details:

- This happens in both Linux Chromium and Windows Chrome.
  Linux Firefox has the characters in the left pane, but not the right.
- The cursor is followed by an "A" that blinks in unison with the cursor.
- There are no errors in the console.
- graphql version is [0.11.11](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/releases).
- Server is Erlang Cowboy with shopgun/graphql

**edit**:

- All instances of `Â` seem to show up beside a `&nbsp;`, as in `Â&nbsp;`
- Possibly related to [HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the response did not specify `charset=utf-8`, hence the default of `ISO-8859-1` was assumed and caused the problem.  Adding `charset=utf-8` fixed everything.