# Google chrome replaces C° with CÂ° in javascript file

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome

I tried to run my code in my google chrome browser (version:71.0.3578.98) on a local python https server but when I try to run it the "C°" is "CÂ°". When I lock in the developer tools it is the same but in the code I have on my Desktop it's "C°" and not "CÂ°".

I tried to use diffrent Browsers (FireFox, Opera) but nothing works.
I found out that when I download the chrome plugin (Set Character Encoding)  and set the encoding to UTF-8 it works and there stands "C°"
but why is chrome this not doing by default

```
var temp = 5;
var str = "Now: " + temp + "C°";
console.log(str);
```

I expected that the chrome browser shows my "Now: 5C°" and not      "Now: 5CÂ°".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the Hex value to see if it works:

```
var temp = 5;
var str = "Now: " + temp + "C\xB0";
console.log(str);
```

If i understood correctly your problem is explain here : http://mc-computing.com/languages/Javascript/Degree_Symbol/Degree_Symbol.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check your character encoding in HTML `<head>` element.

Add following line in  element of your webpage:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```