# Getting "Â" symbol from email message body from "&nbsp" but still encoding as UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, imap, iso-8859-1

First yes I have read

[HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)

Let me explain my script

I have a cronjob that runs a php script using [php-imap-client](https://github.com/SSilence/php-imap-client) to retrieve emails from an inbox. At the top of this script I set `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Even though I have set the encoding to UTF-8 I am still seeing that `&nbsp` is being encoded as `Â`

Eventually, the message body is inserted into MySQL and I can see the `Â` record so I know it is happening before MySQL. I double checked and MySQL is set to UTF-8 as well.

I also set the message body when retrieved with `$message = utf8_encode($message)` and that did not work

Is it possible to set the encoding on a php script even though it is executed with a cronjob?

Here is how I am retrieving the body of the message with php-imap-client

```
$message = $email->message->html.PHP_EOL;
$doc->loadHTML($message);
$message = $doc->saveHtml();
```

I am just not sure at what point the encoding is screwing up.

Comment: Where do you see it? In HTML? In a file? In the email client?

Comment: Why would you set HTTP response headers on a script run by a cron job? Your text isn't Unicode, so just convert it using `iconv` or something similar.

Comment: I edited my post. I am seeing it when inserted into MySQL

Comment: well @miken32 that fixed the output part, but the insert didnt work.

Comment: You don't "set the encoding of a cron job" you need to deal with the encoding every time you ingest and/or output data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through