# java.lang.String introduces new characters while receiving data in android app

Tags: java, android, string, character-encoding, android-volley

I have an android app which retrieves text data from server.

When I hit the query in the browser the text is received properly as :

> Karnataka govt launches E-Step training program for student
>   entrepreneurs. The program is part of Karnataka Innovation &
>   Technology Society.

When I receive the textual data in app as `java.lang.String` object it is received as :

> Karnataka govt launches E-Step training program for student
>   entrepreneurs.Â The program is part of Karnataka Innovation &
>   Technology Society.

As you see the **Â** character is introduced in the text/String when received as `java.lang.String` object.

How do I stop this from happening? I am using `Volley` for making requests.

Comment: Maybe look at the charset [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom). Though I would suggest `Charset.forName("Windows-1252")` for `ISO-8859-1` as that is a patch browsers do also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an encoding issue. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp) how a space can morph into that A. Try to explicitly tell your program which encoding you are using and make sure it matches. text is not *text*.

Comment: I solved it myself by changing Volley response to explicitly receive data in UTF-8 encoding.<br/>

Previously I was receiving it as<br/> 

`new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));` where `parseCharset()` was returning `"ISO-8859-1"`<br/><br/>

Changed it to `new String(response.data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`<br/>

Marking your comment as answer as you mentioned `Try to explicitly tell your program which encoding you are using and make sure it matches`