# &#xa0; in XML making it unparseable

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

So I have a value in my database which has a non breaking space in the form `&#160;` in it. I have a legacy service which reads this string from the database and creates an XML using this string. The issue I am facing is that the XML returned for this message is un-parseable. When I open it in notepad++ I see the character `xA0` in the place of the non breaking space, and on removing this character the XML becomes parseable. Furthermore I have older revisions of this XML file from the same service which have the character `"Â "` in place of the non breaking space. I recently changed the tomcat server on which the service was running, and something has gone wrong because of it. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp/1462039#1462039) according to which my XML is encoded to `ISO-8859-1;` but the code which I use to convert the XML to string does not use `ISO-8859-1;`. Below is my code

```
private String nodeToString(Node node) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        try {
            Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
            t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));


        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            LOG.error("Exception during String to XML transformation ", te);
        }
        return sw.toString();

    }
```

I want to know why is my XML un-parseable and why is there a `"Â "` in the older revisions of the XML file.

Here is the image of the problematic character in notepad++
[image in notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdJx0.png)

Also when I open my XML in notepad and try to save it I see the encoding type is ANSI, when I change it to UTF-8 and then save it the XML becomes parseable.

**New Info** - Enforcing UTF-8 with `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");` did not work I am still getting the xA0 in my XML.

Comment: Are other characters encoded correctly, or is this a more general encoding problem? (I suspect the latter)

Comment: Other characters seem fine, there is only a problem with the non breaking space character.

Comment: So characters like, say, umlauts `ÄÖÜäöü` are working? (Just picking them, because I've got them readily available on my keyboard ;-) depending on your environment, other test strings may be easier to create).

Comment: I wonder if enforcing the encoding can help?  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

Comment: I can't access the DB currently so it won't be possible for me to check these test strings. But the question I would like to highlight again is that why does xa0 make the XML un-parseable? And is xa0 the correct char for nbsp in UTF-8, and what was the encoding that made nbsp "Â " in older revisions?

Comment: @SusanMustafa Sure I can do that, but before that I would like to know what is the issue here, what encoding is currently being used, what was being used before I made the change in the server. Thanks.

Comment: @arielBodyLotion I like how you think.  hmm, based on my quick research, this weird A character you are seeing might be the hex representation of a nbsp... &#xA0; is another synonym, in hex.

Comment: @SusanMustafa Can you have a look at the post I have added in my question, according to that question 0xA0 is ISO-8951 representation of nbsp. Is that correct? Is my XML currently in ISO-8951 encoding?

Comment: Hi @arielBodyLotion I think it might have to do with your tomcat. It defaults to (ISO-8859-1).  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Character+Encoding
However I believe it is important you put more code samples/perhaps describe the over all flow so we understand how your String is converted into XML , not just Node to String.  

How does your xml <?xml header look like ?> for example?  Any encoding set there? Do you use any stylesheets? etc

Comment: The encoding supplied to the transformer's serializer is not going to make any difference because you are sending the transformed output to a StringWriter.It's what you do with the string returned by your `nodeToString()` method that matters.

Comment: @SusanMustafa the xml header has UTF-8 encoding in the header. And there are no stylesheets in the xml. And I'm using the version 8.5.57 of the tomcat server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my version of java was somehow saving my file in ANSI file format. I saw this when I opened my file in notepad, and tried to save it. The older files were in `UTF-8` format. So all I did was specify `UTF-8` encoding while writing my file.

```
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(fileName.trim()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        try {
            out.write(data);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
```